# android gamepad background service

Tags: java, android, gamepad, gamepad-api

My friends and I are trying to use android gamepad key presses to trigger phone calls. We want this to work even if the device is asleep. What would be the appropriate manner to approach this? I have found android.view.InputDevice and KeyEvent callbacks. Would this work on a task that was in the background and device was asleep?